# Created an android virtual device using command line tools but unable to run it

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, command-line-tool

I have created android virtual device using the command lines tools. I have used below command to create the avd.

```
avdmanager create avd -n TestDevice -k "system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64" -d pixel_6
```

when trying to run this avd using emulator getting an error. Here is the command used to run the avd and the error I'm getting.

```
D:\android_sdk\emulator>emulator @TestDevice
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath D:\android_sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 168.63.129.16
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\AzureLocalAdmin\.android\avd\TestDevice.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
```

Please help me to run the emulator.

Comment: Is C:\Users\AzureLocalAdmin\.android\avd\TestDevice.avd\quickbootChoice.ini exists and you have read acces to it? If yes can you past file content here?

Comment: Hi, I've access to the folder. When i open C:\Users\AzureLocalAdmin\.android\avd\TestDevice.avd folder, there is no quickbootChoice.ini file. Why it is not created?

Comment: you can try to create this file manually with and add this line to it: saveOnExit = true